# Why does $\cot\theta=\tan8\theta$ have two solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is to find the general form of:
$$\cot\theta=\tan8\theta$$

By using $$x=n\pi+\alpha$$

I obtained
$$n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=8\theta$$
and
$$n\pi+8\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$$

Using this formula interchangeably yields two different results.
But only the first one is given as the answer, so why can't I use the formula interchangeably? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You could as well write $n\pi+\dfrac\pi2-\theta=m\pi+8\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. Even though, the form of the answer is different, the set of solutions is the same. This is because $n$ can take negative values also.